# Laminate flooring finishing around door jam

Tags: flooring, finishing, laminate

I just completed my laminate floor and used quarter round trim to cover the edges/gaps in the floor.

I would love to get some suggestions to have good finishing at the door frames as shown in the photo.

I found that I can use wood filler or fill white caulk in the space. Is there any other good options I can choose to improve it and make it look nice. Thank you, wish you all happy new year!!

[image: View of laminate flooring near a door jam]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try fitting scrap pieces cut to fit the opening, but this can be tedious and ultimately not look nice. The easiest way to fill the gaps around the door jamb is with a latex caulking that is colored similar to your laminate floor.

Wood filler will need to be sanded and dries to brittle so that it will later break and crumble. Latex caulk is easy to apply and can easily be formed and smoothed with a putty knife. To ensure an professional outcome you can tape the floor edges surrounding the gap with blue tape. Squirt in the caulk, smooth with a putty knife and remove the tape.

If there are gaps along the wall it's best to leave them open to allow for floor movement. You can, however cover them with floor molding attached to the wall (not the floor).

Comment: Thank you very much. I was not aware of coloured caulk. I think using coloured caulk would be best in my case.

Answer (score 3):

Do you still have any pieces of laminate and willing to some more work? You are supposed to undercut the door jamb with saw and slide the laminate under the jamb for a clean look

Comment: So, I did that on the walls/door where I started flooring, using an osciallting tool, but this door is at the end of the room. I cannot slide a slightly larger piece under...

Comment: @NIT_GUP I managed it with a jointed piece that slid in with the under gap bigger on one side so it could dlide in then back.

Comment: To aid in setting difficult pieces like that, trimming the locking edge and glue it to keep it in place once it is set, helps get past some issues